# Удаленный рабочий стол Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, 1с, windows-server-2012

На Windows Server 2012 установлен 1С.
Пользователи на Windows 7 x64 
подключаются удаленным рабочим столом к 1C.

НО ЕСЛИ ТОЛЬКО ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ закроет 1С и удаленныый рабочий стол, и сразу же
попробует переподключиться, то он  увидит черный экран.

На сервере 1с сразу не запускается.

Вопрос:

Как сделать так, чтобы при закрытии удаленного рабочего стола пользователем сеанс подключения
к удаленному рабочему столу завершался немедленно???

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Пользователь видит черный экран при переподключении если во время предыдущего сеанса были запущены приложения, которые не смогли сами выгрузиться при завершении сеанса.

Очень часто это программы отображения статуса бытовых принтеров, установленных на сервере (которые выводят окошки "печать начата/завершена" и др.)

Под администратором посмотрите, какие процессы с именем пользователя остались висеть на сервере после отключения пользователя

Еще одной причиной может быть таймаут завершения 32-битного спулера (1С - 32-битное приложение)

> При обращении 1С:Предприятия к печати запускается процесс
>   SplWOW64.exe, который автоматически завершается через некоторое время
>   после выполнения задания печати. Задержка завершения процесса
>   SplWOW64.exe позволяет повысить производительность повторных операций
>   печати. Данный процесс используется для преобразований между
>   32-разрядными и 64-разрядными приложениями. Если данный процесс сам не
>   завершился до закрытия "1С:Предприятия", то не происходит и закрытия
>   терминальной сессии.

Решение

> Следует проделать следующие действия:
>
> Уменьшить тайм-аут завершения процесса SplWOW64.exe. Для этого следует в значение системного реестра SplWOW64TimeOut установить в
>   значение 1 (при отсутствии значения его следует создать с типом DWORD
>   (32 бита)).
>   Ветка реестра: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print
>
> Добавить процесс SplWOW64.exe в список процессов, завершаемых при завершении терминальной сессии.
>
> Для этого следует значение системного
>   реестра SPLWOW64.EXE установить в значение 0 (при отсутствии значения
>   его следует создать с типом DWORD (32 бита)).
>   Ветка реестра: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer\SysProcs
>
> [Особенности использования 1С:Предприятия при работе на терминальном сервере](https://its.1c.ru/db/metod8dev/content/4064/hdoc)